# Get a list of all applications I have ever installed on any phone

Tags: applications, google-play-store, data-recovery

This is strongly related to Android market. I have once used an application which I now cannot find using the search function. Unless it was withdrawn, it must still exist and I want to find it. Obviously the search would be easier if I could just manually go through all applications I ever installed on any phone.

Is that possible?

Comment: If it was downloaded from Play Store, you'd find it under My Apps. Every now and then apps get deleted from Play Store though. Except for that, answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if you've already tried this, but there's a tab in the Google play store for all apps installed or not. It's under the my apps and games button.

Comment: Oh silly me, it's indeed there - already installing the app. Funny thing is it was even already installed, I just didn't have icon on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

https://play.google.com/apps

Is where you can see a history of all apps you have ever installed.